# SQL Multiple request

Tags: php, mysql, sql

$catIDs is a serie of values, displayed like this : 11,12,13,14, …

on my sql request i put : WHERE c.IsActive = 1 AND c.PkID = '" . $catIDs . "'

but it doesn't accept more than one argument

with the following code it displays only the last value (not all)

i try an explode to eliminate the ',' and have an array used with a simple for

```
    $result = doQuery("SELECT DISTINCT c.PkID, c.CategoryName
                        FROM  " . HC_TblPrefix . "categories c 
                        WHERE c.IsActive = 1 AND c.PkID = '" . $catIDs . "'
                        ORDER BY c.CategoryName");

    $donnee=explode(",",$catIDs);

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($donnee);$i++)       
     {
        $resultCat = doQuery("SELECT c.PkID, c.CategoryName
                        FROM " . HC_TblPrefix . "categories c
                        WHERE c.IsActive = 1 AND c.PkID = '" . $donnee[$i] . "'
                        ORDER BY c.CategoryName");
    }   

        if(!hasRows($resultCat))
            return 0;

        echo '
        <ul>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($resultCat)){
            echo '
        <li><a itemprop="eventType" href="'/index.php?com=searchresult&amp;t='.$row[0].'" rel="nofollow">'.cOut($row[1]).'</a></li>';
        }
        echo '
        </ul>';
```

Comment: In MySQL, could use IN. **xxx IN (a, b, c,...)**

Comment: Where are multiple requests...???

Comment: What is the origin of $catIDs?  Is it coming from the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$result = doQuery("SELECT DISTINCT c.PkID, c.CategoryName
                    FROM  " . HC_TblPrefix . "categories c 
                    WHERE c.IsActive = 1 AND c.PkID IN ('". implode("', '", explode(",", $catIDs)) ."')
                    ORDER BY c.CategoryName");
```

---

The reason your loop is only returning the last result is because you overwrite `$resultCat` every time, so when your loop is done, it just has the result of the last loop iteration. This ***really*** isn't a good way to do what you want, anyways. Go with the solution above.

Comment: Given that the OP isn't clear about the structure of $catIDs this is probably the safest approach.

Comment: You should probably loop over the explode result with intval before imploding again assuming this is user input.

Comment: @nnichols: Agreed, assuming this is user input. And it's worth pointing out that for any input sanitization, `mysql_real_escape_string` should be used to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1):

If $catIDs is a string then this is sufficient.

```
$result = doQuery("SELECT DISTINCT c.PkID, c.CategoryName
                        FROM  " . HC_TblPrefix . "categories c 
                        WHERE c.IsActive = 1 AND c.PkID IN (" . $catIDs . ")
                        ORDER BY c.CategoryName");
```

If $catIDs is an array then this will work.

```
$result = doQuery("SELECT DISTINCT c.PkID, c.CategoryName
                        FROM  " . HC_TblPrefix . "categories c 
                        WHERE c.IsActive = 1 AND c.PkID IN (" . implode(",", $catIDs) . ")
                        ORDER BY c.CategoryName");
```

Comment: Just to point out (for anyone else that gets help from this post), this solution works fine for looking up integer values (which looks like what the OP wants it for), but this will not work with string values. For that, you would need to enclose each comma-separated value with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.PkID, c.CategoryName 
FROM  " . HC_TblPrefix . "categories c 
WHERE c.IsActive = 1 AND c.PkID IN ('" . $catIDs . "')
```

it has to be formatted like this  `('1','4235','4312')`

Comment: This won't put single quotes between each entry, so you will be searching for the string `'1,4235,4312'`.

Comment: That's not PHP - `str_replace(",", "', '", $catIDs)`

Comment: I was trying to be helpful (instead of critical).  I took it for granted by giving an example that a software developer can get the correct syntax for their language.

Comment: Sorry if my comments came off the wrong way, but I wasn't trying to criticize you for helping. I was just trying to point out areas that need to be corrected in order for your method to work. I thought that you might take the suggestions in my comments and improve your answer by updating it. On a side note, it wasn't me that downvoted this. I learned early on not to discourage people from suggesting solutions unless there is a good reason.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to respond and explain, it is appreciated.  Thank you.